# real-time web notification service

Tags: node.js, sockets, notifications, real-time

I've been trying to build (on my own) a real-time notification system.

The last 2 days I searched a lot and I believe the best and simplest solution is to use `node.js` and `socket.io` to develop it.But I am not aware of neither of these.

Is `node.js` and `socket.io` a good practise to make it happen?

**SPECIFICATIONS**

- Two groups of users which will be stored in DB (simple users & administrators)
- When a simple user post something, the post will be sended to (all) admins
- If admin responds to the post, the response will be sended only to the specific user

Is there any simple example or tutorial in order to start with something?
If anyone can post any example it will be very helpful for me..

Comment: please see the answer

Answer (score 2):

For such task, I would recommend youse MongoDB and Ajax. It's a lot simpler, all you have to do is add ajax code in client side(html) and handle the requests on server side.

Simple example:

Normal user sends the message

`html` file

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "http://myUrl.com/myPath",
  data: { message: "Hello this is a message" },
  contentType: "application/json",
  success: function(data){
  //handle success
  },
  error: function(err){
  //error handler  
  }    
})
```

Server side

```
app.post('/myUrl', function(req, res){

   if(req.body){
     //message handlers here
   }
   Users.find({type: 'admin'}, function(err, users){
     var message = req.body.message;
     for(var i = 0; i < users.length, i++){
       //make sure you have the type as adminPending from the schema in MongoDB
       message.save(//save this message to the database); //save this message to the database as 'adminPendingType'
     }
   })
})
```

Coming to admins, for them to know that they have received a message, you need to make an ajax call each second, this is how facebook/twitter handle most things. So basically asking the server again and again if they have a new inbox.

Admin html

```
function messageGetter(){

    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "http://myUrl.com/didIreceiveAmessage",
      data: { message: "Hello this is a message" },
      contentType: "application/json",
      success: function(data){
        //success handler with data object
        if(data['exists']== "true"){
          //add your data.message to the html page, so it will be seen by the user
        }
      },
      error: function(err){
      //error handler  
      }    
    })

}

setInterval(messageGetter, 1000); //check it each second
```

Server side

```
app.post('/myUrl', function(req, res){

   if(req.body){
     //message handlers here
   }
   Message.find({type: 'adminPending'}, function(err, messages){
     //find the admin info from cookies here
     if(messages.length == 0){
      console.log("No messages pending");
      return false; //exit the request
     }else{
      var admin = req.session.admin.id;  //admin user 
      //handle stuff with admin
      messages['exists'] == true;
      res.send(messages);
      //change the type of message from adminPending to adminSeen
      return false; //exit the message
     }
   })
})
```

This was just a quick simple example on how to do it with ajax and MongoDB with Node. Of course coding will be a lot longer, as you have to deal with changing type of messages and saving them.

Comment: Sorry for answering late.Thanks a lot for your time and your post..I'll take it under consideration.